# Using Python to pull data from MySQL database that fall between two datetimes

Tags: python, mysql, datetime

I am trying to figure out how to pull data from a table that has a column that is called 'sent_time' and the datetime falls between two datetimes. The format, as you can see in the code, is 'YYYY-dd-MM HH:mm:ss' . I keep getting different errors depending on how I change the code. Could you please tell me where I'm going wrong?

I want to give you all the information I have with all the other files and what I'm shooting for to see if you can replicate and actually get it working just to see if it's not just my system or some configuration I have..

I have a database with one table.Lets call it ‘table1’ The table is broken down with columns like this:

sent_time | delivered_time |id1_active |id2_active |id3_active |id1_inactive |id2_inactive |id3_inactive |location_active |location_inactive …..`lots more

Lets say that these are two or more customers delivering goods to and from each other. Each customer has three id#s.

I created a ‘config.ini’ file to make my life a bit easier

```
[mysql]
host = localhost
database = db_name
user = root
password = blahblah
```

I created a ‘python_mysql_dbconfig.py’

```
from configparser import ConfigParser

def read_db_config(filename=’config.ini’, section=’mysql’):
“”” Read database configuration file and return a dictionary object
:param filename: name of the configuration file
:param section: section of database configuration
:return: a dictionary of database parameters
“””
# create parser and read ini configuration file
parser = ConfigParser()
parser.read(filename)

# get section, default to mysql
db = {}
if parser.has_section(section):
items = parser.items(section)
for item in items:
db[item[0]] = item[1]
else:
raise Exception(‘{0} not found in the {1} file’.format(section, filename))

return db
```

And now this is the code that I've been working on that is supposed to pull the rows that fall between two datetimes. But I keep getting this error:

```
   **Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\timerange.py", line 33, in <module>
    dt_start = datetime.strptime(userIn,timeShape)
TypeError: must be str, not tuple**
```

Can you take a look at this and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

timerange.py

```
# Establish a MySQL connection
from mysql.connector import MySQLConnection, Error
from python_mysql_dbconfig import read_db_config
db_config = read_db_config()
conn = MySQLConnection(**db_config)
import xlsxwriter
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
cursor = conn.cursor()

#creates the workbook
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('imhere.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

#formatting definitions
bold    = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
date_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'})
timeShape =  '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'



#actual query
userIn = [input('start date:'),0]
userEnd = [input('end date:'),1]



query = (
    "SELECT sent_time, delivered_time, customer_name, id1_active, id2_active, id3_active, id1_inactive, id2_inactive, id3_inactive, location_active, location_inactive FROM table1 "
    "WHERE sent_time BETWEEN %s AND %s"
)
dt_start = datetime.strptime(userIn,timeShape)
dt_end = datetime.strptime(userEnd, timeShape)
# Execute sql Query
cursor.execute(query, (dt_start, dt_end))
result = cursor.fetchall()


#sets up the header row
worksheet.write('A1','sent_time',bold)
worksheet.write('B1', 'delivered_time',bold)
worksheet.write('C1', 'customer_name',bold)
worksheet.write('D1', 'id1_active',bold)
worksheet.write('E1', 'id2_active',bold)
worksheet.write('F1', 'id3_active',bold)
worksheet.write('G1', 'id1_inactive',bold)
worksheet.write('H1', 'id2_inactive',bold)
worksheet.write('I1', 'id3_inactive',bold)
worksheet.write('J1', 'location_active',bold)
worksheet.write('K1', 'location_inactive',bold)
worksheet.autofilter('A1:K1')



print("sent_time", "delivered_time", "customer_name", "id1_active", "id2_active", "id3_active", "id1_inactive", "id2_inactive", "id3_inactive", "location_active", "location_inactive")
for row in result:
    print(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9],row[10])

# Create a For loop to iterate through each row in the XLS file, starting at row 2 to skip the headers
for r, row in enumerate(result, start=1):  #where you want to start printing results inside workbook
    for c, col in enumerate(row):
        worksheet.write_datetime(r,0,row[0], date_format)
        worksheet.write_datetime(r,1, row[1], date_format)
        worksheet.write(r,2, row[2])
        worksheet.write(r,3, row[3])
        worksheet.write(r,4, row[4])
        worksheet.write(r,5, row[5])
        worksheet.write(r,6, row[6])
        worksheet.write(r,7, row[7])
        worksheet.write(r,8, row[8])
        worksheet.write(r,9, row[9])
        worksheet.write(r,10, row[10])




#close out everything and save
cursor.close()
workbook.close()
conn.close()

#print number of rows and bye-bye message
print ("- - - - - - - - - - - - -")
rows = len(result)
print ("I just imported "+ str(rows) + " rows from MySQL!")
print ("")
print ("Good to Go!!!")
print ("")
```

Comment: Try quoting the datetime %s in the query string: BETWEEN '%s' AND '%s'

Comment: Ok...I did and it now gave me this error..

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\timerange.py", line 27, in <module>
    start_date = datetime.datetime(userIn,timeShape)
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'

Comment: I changed line 27 and 28 to reflect 'datetime(userIn,timeShape)' and 'datetime(userEnd, timeShape)' and now gives me this error

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\timerange.py", line 27, in <module>
    start_date = datetime('2015-09-12 13:12:11')#(userIn,timeShape)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

Comment: @Trent I edited my original code to reflect the changes and to give you more detail on the whole thing I'm doing. I hope that you could try to replicate and maybe figure out how I can get it to work. Any help would be great.

Comment: @JCVanHamme maybe you could take a look at this too?

Comment: I can get it to work if I comment out all the input variables and change the code to: query = (
    "SELECT sent_time, delivered_time, customer_name, id1_active, id2_active, id3_active, id1_inactive, id2_inactive, id3_inactive, location_active, location_inactive FROM table1 "
    "WHERE sent_time BETWEEN '2015-09-12 13:13:12' AND '2015-09-15 16:10:09'"
)

Comment: So that means my input variables are wrong..how can I make my input variables be accepted in place of the datetimes inside the WHERE statement?

Comment: Is anyone still able to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used dateutil.parser.parse in my inputs and was able to get some results...I have a new error but I will be posting it on a now question. Thank you for your help.